# how take screen shot of currently playing video?

Tags: android, video

I'm trying to take a screenshot of the currently playing video. I'm trying with code that successfully takes a screenshot of web view but get not success in taking photo of currently playing video.

The code as follow for web view.

```
WebView w = new WebView(this);

w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
         Picture picture = view.capturePicture();
         Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( picture.getWidth(),
         picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

         Canvas c = new Canvas( b );

         picture.draw( c );

         FileOutputStream fos = null;

         try {
             fos = new FileOutputStream( "/sdcard/yahoo_" +System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg" );

             if ( fos != null )
             {
                 b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos );

                 fos.close();
             }

         } catch( Exception e )
         {
             //...
         }
    }
});

setContentView( w );

w.loadUrl( "http://www.yahoo.com");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible in Gingerbread/Honeycomb.  The video gets displayed in a separate Surface that can't be rendered into a Canvas/Bitmap combo. This might be possible with the TextureView APIs in Ice Cream Sandwich, though I'm not sure.

Comment: may be u are right but still i need to do r&d for i m near to archive this, i get rootview of the screen but not get current view.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on 66CLSjY's answer, [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) has the same interface as [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) but it uses [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) as the backend. If the default configuration won't work with your video format you can enable/disable codecs by recompiling. Here is some sample code:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(mUri);
mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_CODEC);
Bitmap b = getFrameAtTime(3000);
mmr.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this it will gives bitmap for your app screen**

```
View v = view.getRootView();
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

First a method to convert your view into a bitmap

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {

    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) 
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else 
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Then save into the SD, for example:

```
static private boolean saveImage(Bitmap bm, String absolutePath)
{
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try 
    {
    String absolutePath = "your path"
        File file = new File(absolutePath);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos); //PNG ignora la calidad
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        try 
        {
            if (fos != null)
                fos.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Good Luck!